# How to consume clean JSON from twitter in php

Tags: php, json, twitter, foreach

May be I am missing something very basic here, but this is what I tried and in some cases my JSON is not a valid JSON.

**Code** -

```
$hash_tag = $_POST['hash_tag'];
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = "?q=#".$hash_tag."&count=30";
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$data = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
$tdata = json_decode($data);
$newArr0 = array();

foreach($tdata as $k=>$v) {
    if($k == "statuses")
        $newArr0 = $v;
}

foreach ($newArr0 as &$nval1) {
    unset($nval1->source);
    if(isset($nval1->retweeted_status)) {
        unset($nval1->retweeted_status);
    }
}
//stripslashes($newArr0);
$myarray = array('response'=>'1','message'=>'Tweet result', 'tweet_data'=>$newArr0);
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

Like I searched for **Britney** but it gives me an Invalid JSON - [JSON](http://pastebin.com/QK7gz6x7)

Error -

Parse error on line 623:

```
...        "location": "WVU 2017 \u
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

But If I search "sachin" I am getting Valid JSON, Let me know what I am doing wrong here, as I need to send the JSON encoded stream to mobile devices from back end.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response contains no errors. The error is that you are pasting the response into  http://jsonlint.com/ or some other service which clearly cuts the string at exactly the offset you are showing the error.

Stop using the service for such long string and remember to check what you pasted to the original response you got in PHP.

Also, when you have problems like this, cut your logic into smaller parts. Such as

`$tdata = json_decode($data);`

after this do a

`var_dump($tdata);
die;`

as you want to cut out whatever you are doing after getting and decoding the response and narrowing the reason to the failure. The rest of the code is when debugging the response, just noise.

If you only run the code in top, and not manually copy pasting it, it works fine..